# black and white hair texture to colored hair

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I have a picture with white hair and the background is black and i want to make the black background to be transparent and the white hair to be colored or even better if i could add another texture on top of this one and it applies only to the hair somehow. How can i do this? Im still not very good with nodes...

So, Here is the image i got

[image]

Comment: You only want to do image manipulation with compositing right? Nothing really related with hair particle system? And your picture is already rendered or you can make make modification and re-render it?

Comment: The picture above is the image that i want to use as texture so its not particle hair that i have rendered. Its just an image that i found online that i want to use as texture. But as you see the background on this texture is black and the hair is white. And i want to change that with nodes so the black background become transparent and the white hair becomes colored. So i'm not using particles. I try make polygon hair

Comment: And since you want to use node I assume it's with cycle?

Comment: Yeah that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you already made a simple cycle material and UV wrapped your hair texture on your polygon hair.

### Transparency

Since your picture is full black and white you can use it as an alpha mask to mix between your hair color and a transparent shader:

Add --> Shader--> Mix Shader

Add --> Shader--> Transparent BSDF

For the mix shader

- Factor : your picture in an *Image Texture*
- First Shader input : BSDF of the Transparent BSDF node,
- Second Shader input : your color Shader, for the example I simply use a diffuse shader but you can make more complex shader to have a better result
- Output of the Mix Shader to the Sufrace of the Material Output Node

### Apply a texture

Now you can add a texture to your hair.

You can add pretty much any kind of color input, in my example case I used just a noise Texture and a color ramp as the input color of a Diffuse Shader, but you can use an Image Texture or any other input color.

Here is the node setup : [image: Node Setup]